# Grouping Unique Row values Postgis, postgres and Qgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

i was given a task to group rows and so far my sql statements using group by have failed, i have also tried extracting the data uniquely first by the groups then perform an inner join but it doesnt work. i have used select distinct and the only way for me to create a column with just V as the grouping i had to use substr() but have no ideal how to avoid all the other geom values by only taking the first Below is an example of my  spatial data :

```
id,groupname,lat/long
1,  v1 , (40,70)
2,  v2 , (40,75)
3,  v1 ,  (40,74)
```

basically my objective is to group all the V into one line which would be

```
id,groupname,lat/long
 1,v        ,(40,70)
```

where 40,70 would represent the first value detected from the first row representing the group.

Do note that the sql query would be running in postgres SQL. Any advice in having further steps in QGis or using postgis are also good. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Mysql and ms sql are different products from postgresql, next time pls use only relevant product tags, not just any which has the word sql in them!

Comment: oh alright thanks for the tip!  i just used suggested

Comment: Pls do not blame a feature within SO for not checking properly which tags are relevant for your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by the 1st row you mean row with minimum id within the group, then use a subquery to get min(id) per group and join your table on it to get the dpatial value:

```
select tminid, t.gname, t2.latlong
from (select min(id) as minid, substring(groupname,1,1) as gname
      from table
      group by substring(groupname,1,1)) t
inner join table t2 on t.minid=t2.id and t.gname=substring(t2.groupname,1,1)
```

Comment: alright ill give it try. What if i have multiple rows of different group names but the same output. like b1,2,3 to b. within the same table. Does this method applies too ?

Comment: As long as you can distinguish them using their 1st character, yes this method does apply. So, if you have a groupname a1 and ab1, then you have to change the grouping logic.